# Disable and enable different Java versions on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, version, disable-app

I've just downloaded AT Launcher (Minecraft modpack launcher), and it requires *Java 7*, and **DOES NOT** work with *Java 8*. The bad thing is that it doesn't start before you remove Java 8 from the computer, and only have Java 7, so I wonder if I can just disable Java 8 temporarily when the game starts, instead of having to uninstall it?

Is this possible?

Comment: which system (OS) are you running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found **for THIS program** (ATLauncher) was to download a little jar-file called LegacyJavaFixer (specific for only ATLauncher though) and place it in each modpack folder.

It doesn't seem to be possible to do it from batch?

I'll mark this answer as correct as long as noone else posts another "universal" solution.

Thanks to you who have tried to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a batch file, that sets the `JAVA_HOME` directory to JAVA7 before starting your software.